# Error building MiKTeX in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, latex, miktex

I am new to Linux and trying to install MiKTeX on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Following MiKTeX instruction, it says I should put the command   cmake -G "Unix Makefiles". Once, I type it, I get the following error.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:333 (message):
  The program bison could not be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nackasha/Downloads/2.9/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/nackasha/Downloads/2.9/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

I appreciate your input, please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `bison`, a parser generator (the GNU replacement for Yacc).